# Hiding Nav on Scroll and reavaling it on logo hover?

Tags: javascript, html, nav

I m developing a site and I m about to add a little bit of transition to the nav bar, but I have few bugs can anybody help.

The Objective is when you scroll down the nav elements gets hidden and the logo of the site will be at  the fixed position, if you move hover logo the nav appears again.

I think it still needs to be fixed.

Reference Navigation bar: https://www.barackobama.com/

```css
.logo{
 position: fixed;
 }
.navigation{
 position: fixed;
 margin: 50px 20px;
 display: block;
 }
ul li{
 padding: 0 30px;
 display: inline-block;
 }
ul li a{
 color: #646464;
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 600;
 }
ul li a:hover{
 color: #BE9503;
 text-decoration: none;
 }
.main{
 min-height: 1200px;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="navig" id="navhome">
  <div class="logo">
    <img src="images/logo-4.png" width="70">
  </div>
   <nav id="navMain" class="navMain">
  <ul class="navigation">
    <li><a href="#">Dr Ganesh</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Connect</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Achievers</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
</div>
<div class="main"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   if($(this).scrollTop()>100)
    {
     $('.navMain').fadeOut();
    }
    else
     {
     $('.navMain').fadeIn(); 
      }
       $('.navig').mouseenter(function(){
     $('.navMain').show();
     });
  $('.navig').mouseleave(function(){
     $('.navMain').hide();
     });
  
   });
</script>

</div>
```

Comment: when I scroll to the top, ul class hides again?